# I am getting multiple calls from angular to the Post API in Node

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to write a file from the data from the database but I'm getting multiple calls from the angular causing multiple entries of the same data.How can I stop that? And also it is causing to override write file after some time.

I am not getting what exactly should I do. I have tried `subscribing` thing in `service` in angular but it was of no help.
component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModalRef, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { CountryService } from './country.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country',
  templateUrl: './country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: []
})
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
  public modalRef: NgbModalRef;
  public form: FormGroup;
  public selectedCountry;
  public countries;
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public toastrService: ToastrService,
    public modalService: NgbModal, public configService: ConfigService,
    public countryService: CountryService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      country: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
    this.getCountries();
  }

  public getCountries() {
    this.countryService.getCountries((data) => {
      this.countries = data.countries;
    }, (err) => { });
  }

  public selectCountry(country) {
    this.countryService.selectCountry(country, (resp) => {
    }, (err) => { });
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountryService {
  private setHeaders() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    });
    return headers;
  }
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService, public http: HttpClient, public toastrService: ToastrService) { }

  selectCountry(country: any, callback, errCallback) {
       const options = {
      headers: this.setHeaders(),
    };
    this.http.post(this.configService.url + '/selectedCountry', country, options).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      callback(resp);
    }, err => {
      errCallback(err);
    });
  }

  getCountries(callback, errCallback) {
       const options = {
      headers: this.setHeaders(),
    };
    this.http.get(this.configService.url + '/countries', options).subscribe((resp: any) => {
         callback(resp.msg);
    }, err => {
      errCallback(err);
    });
  }

}
```

I want the call to be sent only once, not twice

Comment: how getCountries is triggered? ngOnInit?

Comment: yes.. i have called the function on init so i can get the list from db to select from it

Comment: check if your oninit is being called twice. I have seen it happen before.

Comment: btw. is there a reason why you are writing the service method this way? imho it would be more readable when you just return your http service like: return this.http.get("url") - and subscribe in the component.

Comment: yes if i subscribe that service in the component ts then it would give call to backed every time when i want the data but this way i would have it already with me to use without subscribing it again and again at every call i make

Comment: I don´t think it´s a good idea doing this that way. Please show us the whole component and service code. Really important is the way you are triggering the event in the component so, please show this part too.

Comment: I have put up the whole code if it helps now

Comment: Have you tried setting and checking a new `postRequestCount` variable before making the POST request?

Comment: that for different APi all together. But i am getting HTTP request received for same API more then twice even when oninit is called once only

Comment: getCountries() is getting called twice ?

Comment: yes. getCountries() is getting called twice

Comment: See my answer that checks a variable before invoking `this.http.post` method inside the `selectCountry` method.

Answer (score 1):

Btw. - Please consider adding the NGRX lib in your app.

An angular-service is considered as a data holder. So make there an instance variable. 
It could look like:

```
export class Service{
  private countries;
  ...
  public getCountries(){
     return this.countries;
  }

  public loadCountries(){
     this.http.get("url").subscribe(countries => this.countries = countries);
  }
}
```

Then in your component class, you just get the countries.

```
export class Component{
  public coutries;
  ...
  public ngOnInit(){
    this.countryService.getCountries(countries => this.countries=coutries);
  }
 }
```

And last but not least - load the countries in your AppComponent.

```
export class AppComponent{
  ...
  public ngOnInit(){
     this.countryService.loadCountries();
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason i am not able to use the same way u have mentioned. Its returning the HOST disconnected

Comment: Do you mean "[WDS] Disconnected!"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Somewhere on init
let postRequestCount = 0;

// More stuff …

// Just before doing the POST request inside the `selectCountry` method
if(postRequestCount < 1) {
    http.post(); // TODO : Replace with the actual `post` method
} 
postRequestCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Need all your code if you can do a stackblitz, and like Mateusz said its better to handle state with ngrx if you dont want to call twice to backend or a simple approach its something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-biv6cw.

Answer (score 0):

Change your service method like:

add interface:

```
export interface Country{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Change your method:

```
getCountries(): Observable<Country> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get('pass api url here')
      .pipe(
        map((body: any) => body),
        catchError(error => of(error))
      );
  }
```

In your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe(
          (result: Countries) => {
            this.countries = result;
          },
          err => {
            log.debug('get countries error', err);
          }
        );
      }
}
```